# Unable lazy load in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, lazy-loading

I want lazy loading an array in swift , and here is my code:

[image]
the compiler gave me a strange error，it says I pass an closure to an array ,but I returned a [[[String:String]]] right?

can someone tell me where goes wrong?

Comment: try String:Anyobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lazy var plistArray: [[[...]]]? = { ... }()
```

I think you need `()` right next to `}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parentheses (`()`) to the end of the closure block, after the closing curly brace.